# setting persistent plugin parameters in Joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm developing a Joomla 3.x plugin, and want to be able to change the plugin parameter set in the plugin's manifest file programmatically. I believe I need to use a JRegistry object, but I'm not sure about the syntax.

Here's the issue:

```
// token A is set in plugin params as defined in plugin's XML manifest
var_dump($this->params->get('token')); // prints token "A" as expected

// do some stuff to get a fresh access token, called token "B"
$tokenB = $function_to_get_fresh_token();

// set the new token
if ($tokenB) $this->params->set('token', $tokenB);

var_dump($this->params->get('apptoken')); // prints token "B" as expected
```

the problem is that on subsequent page reloads, the token reverts to `tokenA` rather than what I assumed would be the stored value of `tokenB`.

How do I store the `tokenB` value in the plugin's parameters in the database?

Comment: You need to store() it in JTableExtensions. All you've done there is change the instantiated object.

Comment: Can't you change this under Plugin Manager? Parameters are usually set as fields that then are configurable through Extensions -> Plugin Manager. Unless you have to change it programatically...

Comment: @DavidFritsch-- it must be changed programatically since the token extension routine must be server-side.

Comment: @Elin-- can you provide an example of how this works?

Comment: let me ask you though, do you really want to save it in the table if it is just a token? Or do you just want to have it in the session while the user is logged in?

Comment: @Elin-- it must be saved persistently, which is the title of the question. It's an extended token which is good for months, if not permanent, so it will outlive the session.

Comment: But you mean saved in the database not in a persistent cookie for example.

Comment: @Elin-- yes, in the DB, a persistent cookie won't be usable if there's another user who logs in-- this would be for a service like twitter or facebook where the site itself will be posting on behalf of the site owner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an outline, but something along these lines

```
$extensionTable = new  JtableExtension();
$pluginId = $extensionTable->find('element', 'my_plugin');
$pluginRow = $extensionTable->load($pluginId);

// Do the jregistry work that is needed
// do some stuff to get a fresh access token, called token "B"
$tokenB = $function_to_get_fresh_token();

// set the new token
if ($tokenB) $this->params->set('token', $tokenB);

// more stuff

$extensionTable->save($pluginRow);
```

Comment: @Elin- thanks for that. The one thing I am unclear on is the absence of the bind, since you changed `$this->params` but didn't go back to update the `$plugiRow` prior to saving.

Comment: Save is a short cut method for bind(), check(), store().

Answer (score 3):

This is a working example of how to change plugin params from within the plugin (J! 3.4):

```
// Load plugin called 'plugin_name'
$table = new JTableExtension(JFactory::getDbo());
$table->load(array('element' => 'plugin_name'));

// Params can be changed like this
$this->params->set('new_param', 'new value'); // if you are doing change from a plugin
$table->set('params', $this->params->toString());

// Save the change
$table->store();
```

Note: If new params are added by plugin dynamically and the plugin is saved afterwards, these new params gets deleted. So one way to deal with it is to add those params as hidden fields to plugin's config XML.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time googling and reading and found no real answer to this. Oddly enough this doesn't seem to have been provided for in Joomla. So here's what I ended up doing:

1) build a function to get your plugin ID, since it will change from one installation to another

```
private function getPlgId(){
    // stupid hack since there doesn't seem to be another way to get plugin id
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $sql = 'SELECT `extension_id` FROM `#__extensions` WHERE `element` = "my_plugin" AND `folder` = "my_plugin_folder"'; // check the #__extensions table if you don't know your element / folder
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    if( !($plg = $db->loadObject()) ){
        return false;
    } else {
        return (int) $plg->extension_id;
    }
}
```

2) use the plugin id to load the table object:

```
$extension  = new JTableExtension($db);
$ext_id = $this->getPlgId(); 

// get the existing extension data
$extension->load($ext_id);
```

3) when you're ready to store the value, add it to the params, then store it:

```
$this->params->set('myvalue', $newvalue);
$extension->bind( array('params' => $this->params->toString()) );

// check and store 
if (!$extension->check()) {
    $this->setError($extension->getError());
    return false;
}
if (!$extension->store()) {
    $this->setError($extension->getError());
    return false;
}
```

If anyone knows a better way to do this please let me know!

Comment: JTableExtension  has the find() method which let's you give it an array of options (such as array('element','my_plugin') which will run the where query for you and return the extension_id.     You should use JRegistry to manage the params. Then use save() which does bind, check(), store().

Comment: @Elin-- thanks, but again, any examples would be much appreciated. The Joomla docs are pretty slim.

Comment: Yeah you do really have to look in the places where you would expect to find them and read the doc blocks. Fortunately method names are pretty semantic.